# "String or binary data would be truncated" in update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code:

```
glat += result.geometry.location.lat;
glong += result.geometry.location.lng;
gPostal += postalCode;    

sqlUpdateQuery = "update testlatlong set Lat =@lat,Long =@long where postalcode =@postal";
SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdateQuery, sqlConn);
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@lat", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = glat;
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@long", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = glong;
updateCommand.Parameters.Add("@postal", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gPostal;
updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I kept encountering the issue: "string or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated". The column types for my lat and long are `nvarchar(max)` in my sql tables. What could be the issue in my case?

Comment: Well if it's not lat or long, that leaves `postalcode`..

Comment: How about wrapping your variables in CASTs

Comment: what did you meant by wrapping your variables in CASTs?

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` is 8000 char limit, if I recall correctly. Maybe you should set the debugger on your variables and see how large they are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be these lines:

```
glat += result.geometry.location.lat;
glong += result.geometry.location.lng;
gPostal += postalCode;
```

They just look wrong. All the code you posted look like they are in a loop, for which the postal code will keep growing due to +=, eventually being longer than the size of the column.

Even if the lat and lng are varchar(max), what's it doing incrementally adding to the column value?

Comment: foreach (var result in googleResults.results)
                    {}

Comment: it is wrapped under this loop

Comment: @Spencer: `glat`, `glong`, and `gPostal` are going to keep growing longer and longer with each iteration in the `for` loop. Eventually it will exceed even `nvarchar(max)`.